# Custom paint method in TSplitter doesn't use Vcl Styles colors

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I'm using the code posted in this link [`TSplitter enhanced with grab bar`](http://melander.dk/articles/splitter/) , to draw a grab bar in a splitter control,

```
procedure TSplitter.Paint;
var
  R: TRect;
  X, Y: integer;
  DX, DY: integer;
  i: integer;
  Brush: TBitmap;
begin
  R := ClientRect;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);

  X := (R.Left+R.Right) div 2;
  Y := (R.Top+R.Bottom) div 2;
  if (Align in [alLeft, alRight]) then
  begin
    DX := 0;
    DY := 3;
  end else
  begin
    DX := 3;
    DY := 0;
  end;
  dec(X, DX*2);
  dec(Y, DY*2);

  Brush := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Brush.SetSize(2, 2);
    Brush.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnHighlight;
    Brush.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,1,1));
    Brush.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0] := clBtnShadow;
    for i := 0 to 4 do
    begin
      Canvas.Draw(X, Y, Brush);
      inc(X, DX);
      inc(Y, DY);
    end;
  finally
    Brush.Free;
  end;

end;
```

the code works nicely but when I enabled the vcl styles, the colors used to draw the the splitter and the grab bar doesn´t fit the used by the vcl styles.

[image]

How I can draw the TSplitter using the Vcl style colors of the current theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [system color constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Color_Constants) which uses the code (clBtnFace, clBtnHighlight, clBtnShadow) not store the vcl styles colors, you must use the [`StyleServices.GetSystemColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Themes.TCustomStyleServices.GetSystemColor) function to translate these to the vcl styles colors.

```
procedure TSplitter.Paint;
var
  R: TRect;
  X, Y: integer;
  DX, DY: integer;
  i: integer;
  Brush: TBitmap;
begin
  R := ClientRect;
  if TStyleManager.IsCustomStyleActive then
    Canvas.Brush.Color := StyleServices.GetSystemColor(clBtnFace)
  else
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;

  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);

  X := (R.Left+R.Right) div 2;
  Y := (R.Top+R.Bottom) div 2;
  if (Align in [alLeft, alRight]) then
  begin
    DX := 0;
    DY := 3;
  end else
  begin
    DX := 3;
    DY := 0;
  end;
  dec(X, DX*2);
  dec(Y, DY*2);

  Brush := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Brush.SetSize(2, 2);

    if TStyleManager.IsCustomStyleActive then
      Brush.Canvas.Brush.Color := StyleServices.GetSystemColor(clBtnHighlight)
    else
      Brush.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnHighlight;

    Brush.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Brush.Height, Brush.Width));

    if TStyleManager.IsCustomStyleActive then
      Brush.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0] :=  StyleServices.GetSystemColor(clBtnShadow)
    else
      Brush.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0] :=  clBtnShadow;

    for i := 0 to 4 do
    begin
      Canvas.Draw(X, Y, Brush);
      inc(X, DX);
      inc(Y, DY);
    end;
  finally
    Brush.Free;
  end;

end;
```